# Display a file JSON with vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3, jsonstream

Within the framework of a web application, I want to browse a JSON file to be able to display the data in a boat on a web interface (without saving it in a data structure as it is quite large (about 100MB)) using vuejs.

**The table i want to display:**

| DataName1 | DataName2 | DataName3 | DataName4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Data 4 |
| Data 5 | Data 6 | Data 7 | Data 8 |

I try to use an import JSONStream but i have this error when execut `npm run serve`

```
JSONStream in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/ContentBody.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
```

I tried to install it with :

```
npm install JSONStream
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know if I can use it with the vuejs ? if you have any ideas  about How to display JSON file with vus js or how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: What doesn't work when installing the lib via npm? Your question needs more focus, it's totally unclear. We don't have the json format, we don't know how you import it, and there are several questions in one.

Comment: I don't know of an alternative but I do know that `JSONStream` is a package for node.js servers.  It is incompatible as a frontend library

Comment: when i install with npm install JSONStream i have this message :                                       up to date, audited 2512 packages in 6s

17 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 12 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: Where is your json file located? You can also directly import it or use `fetch` to get it from a server endpoint

Comment: Also please provide a [example], so it can be understood what you actually do